# Is there a way to make the user choose the group he want to display on crystal report?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am making a windows form application using visual studio 2005. My application use SQL server to get data to display in crystal reports. The crystal reports contains groups. can i make the user choose which group he want to display in the report?? I make the report using the report wizard

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague, but in short yes, you can make use an expression to group data in Crystal, and this expression can be set based on a parameter, so as long as your user can pass a parameter to the report, then then will also be able to influence the grouping. If you need a more detailed then you really need to provide a more detailed question.  As an aside, why are you using Visual Studio 2005? It's probably time to upgrade, that is pretty old tech!